# NANT Script Check if Directory is Empty and then delete

Tags: nant

I am trying to do following.
I have a root folder and under that 4 subfolders.

1. Check if a Directory under root is empty or not.
2. if yes, delete the directory.

Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

NAnt's [`delete`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/delete.html) task in addition with NAntContrib's [`fileset::has-files`](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/fileset.has-files%28System.String%29.html) function will do the trick.

**UPDATE:** Here is an example assuming you have a root folder named `foo` and subfolders named `bar1` to `bar4`:

```
<target name="go">
  <loadtasks assembly="C:\YourPathToNAntContrib\bin\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" />
  <property
    name="root"
    value="C:\foo" />
  <property
    name="subfolders"
    value="bar1,bar2,bar3,bar4" />
  <foreach
    item="String"
    in="${subfolders}"
    delim=","
    property="subfolder">
    <property
      name="basedir"
      value="${path::combine(root, subfolder)}" />
    <fileset
      id="files"
      basedir="${basedir}">
      <include name="**/*" />
    </fileset>
    <if test="${not fileset::has-files('files')}">
      <delete dir="${basedir}" />
    </if>
  </foreach>
</target>
```

Comment: can you give me an example please?